# How to join fixed row table against mapping table and reveal unmapped records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables and I am having trouble figuring out how to join them to meet my projection needs. Here is a scenario that illustrates the problem

**1**. The first table has a fixed set of values/rows; in this case *Room Types*

**Room Types**

```
Id | RoomType
--------------
1  | Bed Room
2  | Kitchen
3  | Half-Bath
```

**2**. The second table maps the items from the first table to an instance of a *Property*. One *Property* can have **1 or more** *Room Types*

**Property Rooms**

```
Property | RoomTypeId
---------------------
  ABC    |     1
  ABC    |     3
  EFG    |     1
  XYZ    |     1
  XYZ    |     2
  XYZ    |     3
```

***Note***: some of the above properties are not mapped to some Room Types

**3**. I would like to make a projection that joins the rows in such a way that I can easily account for *Room Types that are mapped and not mapped to a Property*. Here is a sample result:

```
Property | RoomTypeId | PropertyHasRoom
---------------------------------------
   ABC   |     1      |      Yes
   ABC   |     2      |   No or NULL
   ABC   |     3      |      Yes
   EFG   |     1      |      Yes
   EFG   |     2      |   No or NULL
   EFG   |     3      |   No or NULL
   XYZ   |     1      |      Yes
   XYZ   |     2      |      Yes
   XYZ   |     3      |      Yes
```

Can anyone explain how this can be accomplished in T-SQL.

Comment: Do you have a separate table with the list of properties?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a multiplication first - every combination of Property + RoomType. In SQL Server we use a CROSS JOIN for that. Then you need to outer join to the junction table, and conditionally display Yes/No based on whether the junction table had a matching row. This should provide the output you want:

```
SELECT 
  p.Property, 
  RoomTypeID = t.Id, -- why isn't this just called RoomTypeID? 
  PropertyHasRoom = CASE
    WHEN pr.Property IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' 
    ELSE 'No' END -- or just END if you want NULL
FROM dbo.Properties AS p
CROSS JOIN dbo.RoomTypes AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PropertyRooms AS pr
ON p.Property = pr.Property
AND t.Id = pr.RoomTypeID
ORDER BY p.Property, t.Id;
```

Comment: Tried to apply this but I am still not seeing rows that reflect the absence of a match through the junction table. The Cross Join feels right but as I said I am still missing the unmapped records.

Comment: @JoeGeeky this query gets the exact same results your question states you're expecting. Can you provide some sample data and desired results that this query *doesn't* deliver?